# C++ websocket library with no dependency C++11

Tags: c++, websocket, poco-libraries

I want to use websocket library for C++.

But for now, Since i am not sure if the compiler which i will use support C++11, i want one that has not dependency of C++11 or Boost.

And i found POCO c++ library supporting weboskcet.

does this have dependency to C++11 or not?

And it is recommendable for only websocket ?(it seems to be packed with other many libraries together making it heavy)

Comment: Voted to close: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: What's wrong with boost? As far as I know, you could use boost asio (small library) that is not dependent on C++11. It is also clean and idiomatic.

Comment: Because i had problem experience with boost, so i don't want potential problem by boost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POCO doesn't seem to have a dependency on C++11. I remember reading somewhere that it will start using C++11 in version 1.5

Comment: Currently (1.5.x), C++11 dependencies are minimal, optional and disabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 support will be in 2.0, please see [RoadMap](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/wiki/RoadMap).

In regards to dependencies, WebSocket is in the [Net](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/tree/develop/Net) library, which depends on [Foundation](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/tree/develop/Foundation); other Poco libraries are not needed (although you may also want to use NetSSL).